# I am having issue with duplicating laravel user registration form

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I want to make another registration form for creating admin user, this form will be different from the normal registration which will assign the user as admin.
I am duplicating the the registration form. Everything goes fine till I enter values in registration form and hit register button. This gives me error:
"Route [admin] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\courseRecomendation\resources\views\admin\register.blade.php)"

Register blade file

```
   <div class="card-body">
     <form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin') }}">
      @csrf
      
       .................
       .................
                    
       <div class="form-group row mb-0">
         <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
             {{ __('Register') }}
           </button>
         </div>
       </div>
     </form>
   </div>
```

AdminRegisterController

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
// namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AdminRegister;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class AdminRegisterController extends Controller
{
    use AdminRegister;

    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);

        if ($data['role'] === null) {
            $user->assignRole('admin');
        }

        return $user;
    }

}
```

Routs

```
Route::get('/admin/register', 'Admin\AdminRegisterController@showRegistrationForm');
Route::post('/admin', 'Admin\AdminRegisterController@admin');
```

Comment: well the error is already telling you everything you are missing: a route for the name "admin" infact in your route file as far as i can see there is no route called `admin`.. you are probably missing `->name('admin')` on the second route

Comment: @Berto99 Thank you so much. Problem got solved

Comment: no problem, i've created an answer, if you don't mind, mark it as correct, thank you

Comment: sure, no problem

Comment: @Berto99 I make you 4009 cheers

Comment: @TalhaF. ahah thank you, i was 1 point short ahaha

Comment: @TalhaF. 1 short on what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `name` to the route:

```
Route::post('/admin', 'Admin\AdminRegisterController@admin')->name("admin");
```